# My Samsung J2 Prime version 5.4.0 stucked in CHECKING CONNECTION

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-j2

I did HARD FORMAT my Samsung J2 Version 5.4.0 prime and stucked in CHECKING CONNECTION for 1 and a half day. I've tried restarting it and turning it off but it didn't worked. Tried the TALKBACK SETTINGS to use the PRIVACY POLICY (watched it from youtube) but it said "MY REQUEST IS DECLINED" it didn't worked also. Is there's another way to fix it? Please I badly need help.

Comment: https://www.hardreset.info/devices/samsung/samsung-galaxy-j2-prime/recovery-mode

Comment: https://www.techeligible.com/2017/11/26/bypass-google-account-galaxy-j2-prime

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/samloader-download-updates-samsung-galaxy